# How to upload multiple fields and document in firebase?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to make a flutter application which contains a quiz model in it, including Firebase as database. I have a structure for the fields in my firebase which I'm currently following (JSON format of that structure is given below).

The problem I'm facing right now is to upload the database with multiple questions(upto 1000) along with their multiple choice options as currently I'm uploading each questions and options one by one manually. Is there an easier way to upload these question and options to Firestore database?

I thought of converting an excel/csv file to JSON online but it is not giving me the desired output of JSON given below.

This is my JSON format:

```
{
  "Questions":
  {
    "text":"Let S =(1, 2, 3, ... , 100). The number of non-empty subsets A of S such that the product of elements in A is even is :",
    "options":
      [
        {
          "correct" : false,
          "details":"(wrong)",
          "value": "2^100-1"
        },
        {
          "correct" : true,
          "details":"(right)",
          "value": "2^50(2^50-1)"
        },
        {
          "correct" : false,
          "details":"(wrong)",
          "value": "2^50-1"
        },
        {
          "correct" : false,
          "details":"(wrong)",
          "value": "2^50+1"
        }
      ],
      "img": "img url",
      "video": "video url"
  },
  "description": "description",
"id":"id"
}
```

Please let me know, what will be the best solution for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to import that JSON file inside the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model and enter the data and send it as a model using toJson.

```
class QuestionModel {
  Questions questions;
  String description;
  String id;

  QuestionModel({
    required this.questions,
    required this.description,
    required this.id,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'questions': questions.toJson(),
      'description': description,
      'id': id,
    };
  }

  factory QuestionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return QuestionModel(
      questions: Questions.fromJson(map['questions'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      description: map['description'] as String,
      id: map['id'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class Questions {
  String text;
  List<Option> options;
  String img;
  String video;

  Questions({
    required this.text,
    required this.options,
    required this.img,
    required this.video,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'text': text,
      'options': options.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),
      'img': img,
      'video': video,
    };
  }

  factory Questions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Questions(
      text: map['text'] as String,
      options: List<Option>.from(
        (map['options'] as List<int>).map<Option>(
          (x) => Option.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
        ),
      ),
      img: map['img'] as String,
      video: map['video'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class Option {
  bool correct;
  String details;
  String value;

  Option({
    required this.correct,
    required this.details,
    required this.value,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'correct': correct,
      'details': details,
      'value': value,
    };
  }

  factory Option.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Option(
      correct: map['correct'] as bool,
      details: map['details'] as String,
      value: map['value'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**